# Is there a way to use a class attribute as a url parameter on Spring Boot 3?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I started making a small task manager api in order to learn Spring Boot 3. I made a method that lists all tasks, but I want to list them by completed and not completed. My URL is currently like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/tasks
```

What I want is to have a URL parameter that is either true or false:

```
http://localhost:8080/tasks?completed=false
```

Here's the method in the Controller class:

```
@Autowired
private TaskRepository repository;

@GetMapping
public Page<TaskListingData> listAllTasks(Pageable pagination) {
    return repository.findAll(pagination).map(TaskListingData::new);
}
```

Here's the TaskListingData record:

```
public record TaskListingData(Long id, String title, String description, boolean completed) {
    public TaskListingData(Task task) {
        this(task.getId(), task.getTitle(), task.getDescription(), task.isCompleted());
    }
}
```

I know about @RequestParam, but I still haven't thought of a way to change the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the good way :)

You only need to use `@RequestParam` and add some logic inside the controller. Simple example below:

```
@GetMapping
public Page<TaskListingData> listAllTasks(
    Pageable pagination,
    @RequestParam(required = false) boolean completed
    ) {
        if (completed == true) {
            return repository.findAll(pagination)
                .filter() // here you may filter only completed tasks
                .map(TaskListingData::new);
        }
        if (completed == false) {
            return repository.findAll(pagination)
                .filter() // here you may filter only uncompleted tasks
                .map(TaskListingData::new);
        }
        return repository.findAll(pagination).map(TaskListingData::new); // this will happen if you won't pass any value for "completed" param in url, because its value will be null
    }
```

If you this will work for you, please consider creating new method in your repository class, so you will move above filtering logic to such method and inside the controller you will only use it.

Controller methods should be simple and are mostly used only to forward all params to other methods and then to return the final value (paginated objects in your case).

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked. I just changed two things: I used Spring's method name patterns to make to methods in the repository and used a ternary operator in the controller method.

Comment: Great! Good to hear that!

You still can improve this a little bit.

1. Think about listAllTasks() method name. Does it in fact always return all of the tasks?

2. Controller methods are usually using service methods. In your case, it could be single line:

return taskService.getTasks(pagination);

To make it work, you will need simple class, eg. TaskService, with @Service annotation. Inside of TaskService, you can inject (using @Autowired) your TaskRepository bean and use it (in TaskService class), just like you've done it before: repository.find() with some pagination logic.